# Initialize C# List<T> from IronPython?

Tags: ironpython

I have a relatively deep object tree in C# that needs to be initialized from IronPython.

I'm new to python and I'm struggling with the initialization of arrays.

So as an example - say I have these classes in C#

```
public class Class1
{
    public string Foo {get;set;}
}

public class Class2
{
    List<Class1> ClassOnes {get;set;}
}
```

I can initialize the array in Class2 like so:

```
var class2 = new Class2(
    ClassOnes = new List<Class1>()
    {
        new Class1(Foo="bar")
    });
```

In IronPython - I was trying this:

```
bar = Class2
bar.ClassOnes = Class1[Class1(Foo="bar")]
```

But I always get this message:

> expected Array[Type], got Class1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Made a mistake on the Class2() -- that's what I get for making an example instead of posting real code!!!

For what it's worth - I was able to initialize the List with actual instances like this:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

bar.ClassOnes = List[Class1]([Class1(Foo="bar")])
```

Thanks much Cameron!

Comment: No problem ;-) That snippet's interesting, it's creating a Python list with one object in it (a new Class1 object), which the `List<T>` constructor seems to accept as an IEnumerable to create items from. Cool!

Answer (score 15):

You have a couple issues here. First, you're setting `bar` to the class object `Class2` (classes are first-class objects in Python).

You meant to create an instance, like this (with parentheses):

```
bar = Class2()
```

To create a `List<T>` in IronPython, you can do:

```
from System.Collections.Generic import List

# Generic types in IronPython are supported with array-subscript syntax
bar.ClassOnes = List[Class1]()
bar.ClassOnes.Add(Class1())
```

Comment: If you were here - I'd buy you a beer.