# Initializing an Array[int] with Python .Net in Python

Tags: python, python.net

I'm using the [`Python .Net`](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) library so I don't have access to [`List<T>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963918/initialize-c-sharp-listt-from-ironpython). Currently when I try to initialize an Array an error is thrown.

The [documentation](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/readme.html#arrays) has an example that is throwing an error from the latest code base.

**Ex:**

```
from System import Array
myarray = Array[int](10) #TypeError: Cannot convert 10 to System.Int32[]
```

**The following works on 64bit but not on 32bit!**

```
myarray = Array[int]([10]) #OverflowError: value too large to convert
```

Comment: how about `myarray = Array[int]([10])`?

Comment: @njzk2 fairly certain this is a bug I should bring up to the maintainers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also get an error when I execute `Array[int](10)`. It looks like the expected argument isn't the size, but a Python list. The following works for me:

```
py_array = [1, 2, 3]
net_array = Array[int](py_array)
```

Now, `net_array.Length` should return 3.

Comment: This is the same example I have above, it works on 64-bit but not on 32-bit, this is most likely a bug in the package

Comment: I'm running PythonNet in 32-bit mode, and the example I gave above works fine.

Comment: How did you install Python .Net? The package maintainers were able to reproduce it here, https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/58

Comment: I got the source code from http://sourceforge.net/p/pythonnet/code/147/tree/trunk and compiled it for x86.

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Array.CreateInstance(<type>, <length>)`

refer to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_CreateInstance_System_Type_System_Int32_)

Answer (score 0):

you can just write like this:

```
myarray = Array[int]
```