# IronPython create generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, inheritance, ironpython

It is possible to create a generic class in IronPython? I want to inherit from a generic c# class and implement a custom IronPython class on top.

for example:

```
public class A<T>
{

}
```

First IronPython class:

```
class B[T](A[T]): # Problematic part. I don't know how to create a
                  # generic ironpython class
```

Second IronPython class:

```
class C(B[object]):
```

So in the first IronPython is the problem. I don't now hot to create a generic class to pass the type. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

I don't just want to use generic c# classes. I want to implement my own in IronPython and inherting from a c# class.

**EDIT2**

What I want to achive is a class `A` that has a python base class `B`, which should have a generic C# baseclass `C`. The python baseclass `B` is independent of the type of the C# baseclass `C` (it's just a specialization of the generic C# class), but it has to initialize the correct C# base class.

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize C# List<T> from IronPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963918/initialize-c-sharp-listt-from-ironpython)

Comment: @FrankV it' s complet different. I want to create my OWN generic class in IronPython, not just use tham.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Iron)Python is a dynamically typed language, there is no such notion of generic classes in python. You can derive from a generic .NET class, but you can't actually create a generic python class, there is no such thing.

You can however mimic the syntax with the use of some decorators.

```
class B(object):
    class _Meta(type):
        def __getitem__(cls, t):
            from System.Collections.Generic import List as A # just an example
            class _B(A[t]):
                pass
            return _B
    __metaclass__ = _Meta

class C(B[object]):
    pass
```

Your actual implementation of `B` is the class `_B` in the example.

Comment: Ok, works perfectly. But when i want to add some custom methods to `B`, why must the declared in `_B`. If i declare them in `B`, i get the message: `_B` as no attribute `Add2`? Placing `Add2` in `_B` and every thing works. Thank you!