# New Floor.Create() method Revit 2023 APIs with Python

Tags: python, revit-api, floor, pyrevit

I'm currently working on developing a Revit plugin through pyRevit and I'm having some trouble creating a new Revit triangular Floor starting from three vertices defined in Python. I am new to Revit APIs and I'm currently using Revit 2023.

I am aware that there are some changes in APIs with respect to previous releases, such as the new Floor.Create() method. However, when I run my code, I get the error message "*ArgumentException : The input curve loops cannot compose a valid boundary, that means: the "curveLoops" collection is empty; or some curve loops intersect with each other; or each curve loop is not closed individually; or each curve loop is not planar; or each curve loop is not in a plane parallel to the horizontal(XY) plane; or input curves contain at least one helical curve. Parameter name: profile at Autodesk.Revit.DB.Floor.Create(Document document, IList`1 profile, ElementId floorTypeId, ElementId levelId)*".

Upon further inspection, I have checked the CurveLoop() and everything seems to be in order (it's planar, closed, and counterclockwise). I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

```
#! python3

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# IMPORT LIBRARIES
#  System library
import sys

#  Autodesk Revit API
import clr
clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
clr.AddReference('RevitAPIUI')
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import Transaction
from Autodesk.Revit.UI import TaskDialog
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import *
from Autodesk.Revit.DB import XYZ, UV, Line, CurveLoop, Level, Floor, FloorType
from System.Collections.Generic import List

# Function to convert centimeters to feet
def centimeters_to_feet(centimeters):
    return centimeters * 0.0328084

doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document

# Coordinates
a = 0.0
b = 10.0
c = 0.0

# Input elevation (in centimeters)
elevation_cm = c
elevation_ft = centimeters_to_feet(elevation_cm)

# Create a new level at the given elevation
new_level = None

# Start a new transaction to modify the Revit document creating a new level
transaction = Transaction(doc, 'Create New Level')
transaction.Start()

try:
    new_level = Level.Create(doc, elevation_ft)
    
    # Assign a new name to the level
    new_level_name = "elBS_BuildingStorey_{:.0f}cm".format(elevation_cm)
    new_level.Name = new_level_name

    transaction.Commit()
except Exception as e:
    # If an error occurs, roll back the transaction and show an error message
    transaction.RollBack()
    TaskDialog.Show('Error', 'Failed to create level. Error: {}'.format(e))

if new_level:
    TaskDialog.Show('Success', 'Level created at elevation: {} centimeters'.format(elevation_cm))

# Create new floor

point0 = XYZ(a, a, c)
point1 = XYZ(b, a, c)
point2 = XYZ(b, b, c)

line01 = Line.CreateBound(point0,point1).ToRevitType()
line12= Line.CreateBound(point1,point2).ToRevitType()
line23 = Line.CreateBound(point2,point0).ToRevitType()

curveloop = CurveLoop()

curveloop.Append(line01)
curveloop.Append(line12)
curveloop.Append(line23)

print("numberOfcurves: ",curveloop.NumberOfCurves())
print("IsOpen: ",curveloop.IsOpen())
print("HasPlane: ",curveloop.HasPlane())


# Collect floor types
floortypes = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(FloorType)
floortypes = [f for f in floortypes]
floortypes_id = [f.Id for f in floortypes]
floortype_id = floortypes_id[0]
print("floortype id:",floortype_id)

# Collect building storeys
el_BuildingStoreys = FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(Level)
el_BuildingStoreys_id = []
for el in el_BuildingStoreys:
    el_BuildingStoreys_id.append(el.Id)
level_id = el_BuildingStoreys_id[0]
print("level id: ",level_id)

# Start transaction
t = Transaction(doc, "Create new floor")
t.Start()

# Create the floor
new_floor = Floor.Create(doc, List[CurveLoop](curveloop), floortype_id, new_level.Id)
t.Commit()
```

Comment: You shorten and simplify your code a bit using the filtered element collector [`FirstElementId` Method](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/b1b42ac5-e816-983a-f44d-5cf441ca1ad9.htm). I don't see off-hand what is causing the problem, though.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Floor.Create sample code](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/a9c74a9f-46eb-a1b7-608e-2039f06be579.htm)?

Comment: @JeremyTammik thanks a lot for your reply. I have looked at the sample code. I tried to run the Python code in Dynamo instead of in pyRevit and it works, but I do not understand why. The issue is therefore still open since I need to work in pyRevit.

Comment: Glad to hear that it works in Revit API and Dynamo. Unfortunately, I know absolutely nothing about pyRevit, so I cannot help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but when using pyRevit it is using IronPython and not python. Therefor when calling the method Floor.Create() you have to create a C# list;

```
#create the floor
curveLoops = List[CurveLoop]()
curveLoops.Add(curveloop)

new_floor = Floor.Create(doc, curveLoops, floortype_id, new_level.Id)
```

[Initialize C# List<T> from IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963918/initialize-c-sharp-listt-from-ironpython)

I made the change to your code and tested it, and it works for me.

I also removed the ToRevitType when creating the lines, shouldn't be necessary.